# Pandas: IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to run what I think is simple code to eliminate any columns with all NaNs, but can't get this to work (`axis = 1` works just fine when eliminating rows):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,np.nan,np.nan], 'b':[4,np.nan,6,np.nan], 'c':[np.nan, 8,9,np.nan], 'd':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})

df = df[df.notnull().any(axis = 0)]

print df
```

Full error:

`raise IndexingError('Unalignable boolean Series provided as 'pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match`

Expected output:

```
     a    b    c
0  1.0  4.0  NaN
1  2.0  NaN  8.0
2  NaN  6.0  9.0
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), because filter by columns:

```
print (df.notnull().any(axis = 0))
a     True
b     True
c     True
d    False
dtype: bool

df = df.loc[:, df.notnull().any(axis = 0)]
print (df)

     a    b    c
0  1.0  4.0  NaN
1  2.0  NaN  8.0
2  NaN  6.0  9.0
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Or filter columns and then select by `[]`:

```
print (df.columns[df.notnull().any(axis = 0)])
Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')

df = df[df.columns[df.notnull().any(axis = 0)]]
print (df)

     a    b    c
0  1.0  4.0  NaN
1  2.0  NaN  8.0
2  NaN  6.0  9.0
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Or [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) with parameter `how='all'` for remove all columns filled by `NaN`s only:

```
print (df.dropna(axis=1, how='all'))
     a    b    c
0  1.0  4.0  NaN
1  2.0  NaN  8.0
2  NaN  6.0  9.0
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Ahhhh, because the `df[]` method is looking for a row-based index, not a column-based index.  Got it, thank you.

Comment: @pshep123 -  Glad can help!

Comment: It's counterintuitive, because the simplest form of indexing a dataframe is associative, i.e. selecting columns with one of the column headers thus: `df['headername']`

Comment: I was looking for df.loc for using two conditions on columns together (by '&'), didn't know ':,' was important in  df.loc[:,<conditions>]. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas.DataFrame.dropna) with `axis=1` and `thresh=1`:

```
In[19]:
df.dropna(axis=1, thresh=1)

Out[19]: 
     a    b    c
0  1.0  4.0  NaN
1  2.0  NaN  8.0
2  NaN  6.0  9.0
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

This will drop any column which doesn't have at least 1 non-NaN value which will mean any column with all `NaN` will get dropped

The reason what you tried failed is because the boolean mask:

```
In[20]:
df.notnull().any(axis = 0)

Out[20]: 
a     True
b     True
c     True
d    False
dtype: bool
```

cannot be aligned on the index which is what is used by default, as this produces a boolean mask on the columns

Comment: Thanks Ed - I wasn't aware of the `thresh` param.  Just learned that you can use both axes simultaneously to trim all null rows and columns: `df = df.dropna(axis = [0,1], how = 'all')`

Comment: Yes it's pretty flexible and useful method

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue while using a function in fairlearn package. Resetting the index inplace worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I came here because I tried to filter the 1st 2 letters like this:

```
filtered = df[(df.Name[0:2] != 'xx')]
```

The fix was:

```
filtered = df[(df.Name.str[0:2] != 'xx')]
```