# why we not able to print column name which have dtype=='object'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
```

train =pd.read_csv("https://datahack.analyticsvidhya.com/media/workshop_train_file/train_gbW7HTd.csv")

```
train[train.dtypes=='object']
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match
```

Comment: I ran your script on my machine. I see no errors.

Comment: i run on jupyter notebook    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:2: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
  
---------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: when i use train.dtypes.loc[train.dtypes='object'] then it will print it

Comment: Not sure how that changes things. Check this link for similar issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45352909/pandas-indexingerror-unalignable-boolean-series-provided-as-indexer

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `.loc`. Try this:

```
df.loc[:, df.dtypes == 'object'].head()
```

[image: output]

Or if you just want the column names:

```
df.columns[df.dtypes == 'object']
```

Comment: but train[train.dtypes=='object'] why this comes errror

Comment: Maybe from your version of Pandas? I'm on `0.22.0` and I get the same error as you. Maybe @Krishna is on a different version?

Comment: @amitparajapat, `train[train.dtypes=='object']` - this way you are filtering rows, not columns. Better use solution provided by Ian or a bit more mosnterous: `train[train.columns[train.dtypes=='object']]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DataFrame.select_dtypes()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) method:

```
train.select_dtypes(['object'])
```

to select all non-numeric columns (strings, datetimes, etc.):

```
train.select_dtypes(exclude='number')
```

Demo:

```
In [92]: train.select_dtypes(['object']).head(2)
Out[92]:
          Workclass  Education      Marital.Status       Occupation   Relationship   Race   Sex Native.Country  \
0         State-gov  Bachelors       Never-married     Adm-clerical  Not-in-family  White  Male  United-States
1  Self-emp-not-inc  Bachelors  Married-civ-spouse  Exec-managerial        Husband  White  Male  United-States

  Income.Group
0        <=50K
1        <=50K

In [93]: train.select_dtypes(exclude='number').head(2)
Out[93]:
          Workclass  Education      Marital.Status       Occupation   Relationship   Race   Sex Native.Country  \
0         State-gov  Bachelors       Never-married     Adm-clerical  Not-in-family  White  Male  United-States
1  Self-emp-not-inc  Bachelors  Married-civ-spouse  Exec-managerial        Husband  White  Male  United-States

  Income.Group
0        <=50K
1        <=50K
```