# How to fix Pandas: IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I apologize ahead of time if I've done anything wrong in posting this question. I'm new to coding as well as the stackoverflow community.

The following is my code:

```
def duplicate_check(sheet_name, filename, last_row_column, dupe_column):
data = pd.read_csv(filename)
last_record = (data[last_row_column].last_valid_index())
df2 = data.loc[:last_record]
indices = df2[(df2[dupe_column]).isnull()].index
duplicates = df2.duplicated(subset=[dupe_column], keep=False)
duplicates_sum = duplicates.sum()
duplicate_data = (data.loc[duplicates, :])
export_csv = duplicate_data.to_csv(full_file_string,index=None,)
```

And I am getting the following error:

> Unalignable boolean Series provided as 
>   pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45352909/pandas-indexingerror-unalignable-boolean-series-provided-as-indexer) example, but I was not sure how to apply the solution to my code as I was already using 'loc'.

The expected output is to have the duplicates saved onto a csv. Please let me know if there is anything I should clarify! I really appreciate any help I receive, this has been driving me crazy.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. Can you provide a [mcve] ?

Comment: Yes! Thank you for the feedback. The code should reflect only the important stuff. Please see the edited code and let me know if I should make any other changes or clarify further.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59147218/how-to-fix-pandas-indexingerror-unalignable-boolean-series-provided-as-indexer?noredirect=1#comment104520329_59147218